# SAS Enterprise Guide Read Uncommitted in Query Builder

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am trying to figure out a way to change the isolation level to read uncommitted (RU) prior to my query running from query builder, as I sometimes need to get data from operational tables.

Is there a way to do this in SAS Enterprise Guide?  I know in the Options menu, there is a place to run custom code before task and query code, but I don't know what to enter here to make this happen.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you querying - SAS datasets, SQL Server, Hadoop, etc.?  And how is it defined in SAS - are you using a metadata defined library?  Or are you defining the library or connection yourself?

Comment: This is for querying SQL server; I've added the connections to my ODBC Administrator in Windows, and then am running auto code at server connect to define the libraries (if that makes sense).  Sorry if it doesn't - I'm still rather new with SAS.

Comment: What you are doing sounds right, Please provide a screenshot or  more details on what you are doing in your EG Project. I will put an initial answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer - it depends.  The part where you force an uncommitted read is configured in the libname definition.  If your libname is defined in metadata, then no - you can't do it in EG (at least not using a wizard), you'll need the library manager in SMC or DI studio.

If your libname is defined programmatically, then the syntax depends on what flavour of database you are using.  For SQL Server, you'd need to add the following option: `Read_Isolation_Level=RU`.

Note that this can mean that you read 'dirty data' (see this communities [thread](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Data-Management/Should-I-use-Dirty-Reads-Will-it-improve-performance-or/td-p/160936)).

Comment: The code that loads on server connection (from options in sas) is as follows - 

`%include "y:\autoexec.sas";`

That file includes the following connection - 

`libname MS_SQL ODBC datasrc="MS SQL Server Connection" schema=dbo;`

Can I add the Read_Isolation_Level=RU to the end of that to acheive what I am looking for?

`libname MS_SQL ODBC datasrc="MS SQL Server Connection" schema=dbo Read_Isolation_Level=RU;`

Answer (score 0):

In your Auto load program that defines the libraries; you just need to know the name of the SQL library you want to query. Then do the following steps:

1. In your EG project: create a new program: File / new / Program, This will add a new program to your flow.
2. If the libname of the SQL library is called 'SQL' and the table you want to query is 'ORDERS'; you use `PROC SQL` which is very similar to MS-SQL, then click run or F8.

   `proc sql;
   select id, sum(sales) as total_sales
   from SQL.ORDERS
   group by id
   ;
   quit;`

**Example**

Step 1:

[image: step 1]

Step 2:
[image: Step 2]

[image: New Program]

[image: Run]